# Spring JPA repository findOne() with ID column called "name"

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I can't find anything in the docs about this but is findOne()/getOne() simply and alias for findById()?

I have an entity which looks like this

```
public class Tag {
  @Id
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

and a repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, String> {
  Tag findByName(String name);
}
```

this code works fine:

```
void saveTag() {
  Tag tag = repository.findByName("test");
  if (tag == null)
    tag = new Tag("test");
  tag.save();
}

saveTag();
saveTag();
```

However this blows up:

```
void saveTag() {
  Tag tag = repository.findOne("test");
  if (tag == null)
    tag = new Tag("test");
  tag.save();
}

saveTag();
saveTag();
```

At this point I get a DuplicateKeyException because the call to findOne() always returns null even though it exists in the DB

Comment: Have you checked what `SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(…)` actually does? If `EntityManager.find(Class<?>, Object)` does not return anything for `Tag` and `"name"` there's hardly anything we can do about it…

Comment: entityManager.find(Tag.class, "test") also works ok as does repository.findByName("test"), the only problem is with repository.findOne("test")